# Put error message when value is initial at the end of the new row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've table with inline create i.e. you click on add row and it open you editable row which you can put data and in the editable row you have save button.

when user click on button save button ('#btnsubmit') I want that if property name is initial to add error message in red in the right side of the table row,i've no idea
how to do that,any idea?

```
td><input id="btnsubmit" type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" /></td><td></tr>';

        function addRow() {
            if ($('#btnsubmit').length == 0) {

                jQuery(html).prependTo('#data-table');

                $('#btnsubmit').click(function () {
                $('#checkBox1').attr('disabled', 'true');
                $('input').attr('readonly', true);
                $('input[type=checkbox]').attr('readonly', true);
                });

            }
        }


 var html = '<tr><td>@Html.TextBox("name")</td><td>@Html.CheckBox("checkBox1")</td>input id="btnsubmit" type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" /></td><td></tr>
```

UPDATE

```
$('#btnsubmit').click(function () {

            $(".errmsg").remove();
            $(".err").removeClass('err');

            var row = $(this).parent();
            var nameval = document.getElementById('name');
            var val = nameval.value;
            if (val.trim().length < 1) {
                nameval.addClass('err');
                var err = $("<div class='errmsg'>field empty</div>");
                row.after(err);
```

in the line of nameval.addClass('err'); I got error in the inspect element 
uncouget error :undefined is not a function,any idea?

Comment: shouldn't be a problem.. just if you could make a fiddle with valid code, that works up to the point of your question.. and from there I'll do my best :)

Comment: @EyalBarta- please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/GHw9q/2/

Comment: ok great, now when click on 'addnew-button' button it adds the new row right? in what case do I get an error? what do you mean by 'if property name is initial'

Comment: @EyalBarta-  if user doesnt provide any value to value field :)where there is value aaa...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is more or less what you want..

http://jsfiddle.net/GHw9q/3/

basically I updated your addnew-button click handler to this:

```
 $('.addnew-button').click(function(){
        $(".errmsg").remove();
        $(".err").removeClass('err');            

        var _row = $(this).parent();
        var _input = _row.children('.data-category');
        if (_input.val().trim().length<1) {
            _input.addClass('err');
            var _err = $("<div class='errmsg'>field empty</div>");
            _row.after(_err);
        }
        else {
            $(this).remove();
            initRowEvents(jQuery(document));
        }

    });
```

and added some css.. check it out.. let me know if you have any questions

---

if using the variable html:

```
var html = '<tr><td>@Html.TextBox("name")</td><td>@Html.CheckBox("checkBox1")</td><td><input id="btnsubmit" type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" /></td></tr>';
```

notice firstly, I've fixed some errors you had in the variable..

the code should be same as above, only the _input variable should change to:

```
   var _input = _row.find('input').filter(":first");
```

** this counts on your 'name' input field to be the **first** input in the tr..

Comment: This example actually checks for value in both fields, but could easily be simplified if you need to check only 1 of them..

Comment: Eyal thank you very much but I need to check only one field just the first one.Thanks a lot!Voted up!

Comment: no problem, I've updated my answer to check only 1.. good luck !

Comment: HI Eyal,i've little problem.in the post at the bottom this are the fields which related to the new row(in var html) which is little bit different from the code in the JSfiddle and what you refer to in the code: _row.children('.data-category');,how should I adopt it? Thanks a lot for the support!

Comment: sure,  _row.children('.data-category') is just the way for me to find the field we want to check, if the html is different, you just need to find the right selector that will find the field.. if you want to show me the html I can help you with the selector

Comment: the best is if we can relate the button we clicked to the field element we're looking for... in your 'var html' where would the actual add button be? inside the <tr>?

Comment: Correct eyal this is the button which user click to save the entire row data

Comment: I've update the post with the button please have a look.

Comment: @JeanTehhe I've updated the answer above, look below the line.. cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot Eyal,I debug the code and in the value of the _input and also in the _row I get the same value ="Create",how should I change it to provide the textBox name value?

Comment: what does '@Html.TextBox("name")' render? can you post from your browser the actual HTML that is rendered?

Comment: HI Eyal -ive tried to deal it myself and I was able to get the value of the field but I got error in the code please see my update post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54876/discussion-between-eyal-barta-and-jean-tehhe).